# Checking checkbox using `<label>` in `<tr>`

Tags: html

I'm trying to check  a `checkbox` using `<label>` but by clicking a row / `<tr>` of `<table>`. ***Is this possible??***

I have tried to use jQuery, but I'm not quite satisfied with the result, because, I'll eventually **select** the texts inside the row, which isn't very user friendly
I also have tried to test it in HTML on Chrome

```html
<table border="1">
  <label>
  <!-- This label is expected to be used to check on the checkbox by 
       clicking anywhere on the table row -->
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /> Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>

  </label>
</table>
```

I expected when I click `bar` the checkbox would be checked, but it didn't

**Note:**

Since this is impossible to be aquired through basic HTML,  I'm going to close this question

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a label there.

Comment: So basically you're saying, with basic HTML, I can't check the checkbox by clicking the row right? @Quentin

Comment: Can I help you out using jQuery?

Comment: No. Don't need. I have found that this is impossible just by using basic HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve this by basic HTML as of now...

Based on W3, it said that `<label>` can only affect on one level of container only

Something like this:

Legal:

```
<label>
  <div> AAAA</div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  Some text
</label>
```

Illegal:

```
<label>
  <div> AAAA
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  Some text
</label>
```

So since my question is involving more than one level of containers, It can't be achieved by normal means

Reference:

[Mozila Web Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Headings)

Answer (score 4):

Please set label for attribute to do this, below code will help you.

```html
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" /> Foo</td>
            <td><label for="mycheckbox">Bar</label></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I hope OP would accept it as an answer.

Comment: No. What expect is, if I click anywhere in the table "row", the checkbox would be checked.
The reason I don't use for, is because I'll make a table with a lot of data's inside. and I'll run out of id, and space to write it

Comment: I put an another answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.checkBoxChecked').on('click', function(){
 var checkbox = $(this).find('.Aps_checkbox');
   checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr class="checkBoxChecked">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="Aps_checkbox"/> Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkBoxChecked">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox2" class="Aps_checkbox"/> Foo2</td>
        <td>Bar2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Please Use this code for click on row with checkbox

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple labels can be associated with the same form control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Clicking on any of the labels associated with an `input` element toggles the `checked` state of that `input` element.

To check a checkbox by clicking a table row, you can create a table where the first `td` element of each table row contains an `input` element, and the subsequent `td` elements contain labels for that input element, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="foo">Foo Label 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="foo">Foo Label 2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="bar" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="bar">Bar Label 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="bar">Bar Label 2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To maximize the clickable area of each table row, you can make each `label` element fill the width of its parent `td` element like so:

```
table td label {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you're gonna run out of #id's to put in and you can dramatically increase the HTML size with the unnecessary <label> tag.
It would be nice if we could implement an on click on the <tr> instead which looks for the checkbox and enable it directly through JavaScript.